# How to get a gradient like this in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, gradient

I am trying to create an exact gradient. but no success. I tried adding Colors values but was not getting the below result. I am completely new to flutter and any kind of help will be appreciated!

[image]

My code:

```dart
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {

    final rect = new Rect.fromLTWH(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height);
    final gradient = new LinearGradient(
      colors: [Color(0xffF3985F),Color(0xffF28053),Color(0xffF36456),Color(0xffF24F58),Color(0xffF24D67)],
      //stops: [0.0, 1.0],
      begin: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
      end: FractionalOffset.topRight,
    );

    var paint1 = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(rect)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
    //a rectangle
    canvas.drawRect(Offset(0, 0) & Size(width, 0.35 * height), paint1);
  }
```

Comment: do you want to do it with a customPainter? you could just use a Container or DecoratedBox as well it would be much easier.

Comment: How to do with container? I need a bruteforce process to this. Though CustomPainter will be appreciated!